# socket.io - socket is not defined on client only

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm running two instances of socket.io on my local machine (two namespaces). The present issue is that when trying to connect from the client side (to *any* namespace), I get the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: socket is not defined`

I tested this without custom namespaces and the same issue arose. The server side is just fine as I can emit events.

The Client code looks like this:

**Client**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
var socketOptions           = {};
socketOptions.transports    = ['polling'];
var client                  = new PlayClient();

var playSocket  = io.connect('http://localhost:8044/clients', socketOptions);

playSocket.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.clear();
    console.info("CLIENT: Connected.");

    socket.on("client:change scene", function(newSceneId) {
        console.log(newSceneId);
        client.changeScene(newSceneId);
    });

});
</script>
```

It looks like I just overwrote the socket. So, basic troubleshooting led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37726357/10519799) leading me to confirm that. **However,** passing `(data)` or something else instead still leaves `socket` undefined but with the console declaring: `TypeError: undefined`.

If I change `.on('connect')` to `.on('connection')`, the socket is no longer overwritten but fails to connect or receive any emitted events because [the socket.io *client* does not understand the 'connection' event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49099427/10519799).

Any help with this is much appreciated, as I seem to be caught in a circular rut.

Comment: you don't get passed a "socket".  the code in the function should refer to `playSocket`

Comment: Thank you Sam! That has fixed it. It wasn't entirely clear to me in all the docs examples that the namespaced socket is never passed when referenced on connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to be confusing server side and client side events; they are pretty different.  each client object can only be connected to a single server, while the server can receive many connections

maybe try something like:

```
var playSocket  = io.connect('http://localhost:8044/clients', socketOptions);

playSocket.on('connect', function() {
    console.clear();
    console.info("CLIENT: Connected.");
}

playSocket.on("client:change scene", function(newSceneId) {
    console.log(newSceneId);
    client.changeScene(newSceneId);
});
```

Comment: No worries Sam -- looks like you posted before my comment response above. In my case there's only a client page and a server; the client page never creates more than the single socket object to connect to the server. Good to know though for the future, because there might be a (far-off) future case for me where the client page here needs to connect to multiple **servers** simultaneously.

Comment: that's fine; you'd just create multiple client objects in the web page, each one connects to a single server…  if my answer solves your original question you can mark this as "accepted" which helps other people direct their attention to other "unanswered" questions

Comment: FYI: the Network tab in (e.g.) Chrome dev tools displays websocket frames as they move over the network.  can be great for debugging your own code, as well as seeing how other sites use them